# How to align with margin on Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

I hope I'm not asking a question that was answered before. I searched.

I need to do something similar to what the article below explains for Delphi 2006+. Can it be done on Delphi 7 without using a Panel or GroupBox?

http://delphi.about.com/od/vclusing/a/margins-padding.htm

**Edit**: If the answer is "no", is there any kind of difference between using a TPanel or TcxGroupBox (DevExpress) as a dummy component for a margin?

Comment: I don't understand the second part of your question. How exactly are you using these components to generate a margin?

Comment: From top to bottom : TcxButton Align = Bottom; TcxGroupBox Align = Bottom Height = 50; TcxButton Align = Bottom. This way you have a 50 pixel margin between each button. Link : http://imgur.com/kVa7g

Comment: I can't see any problem doing it the way you do.

Comment: Well, this way I need to use a useless Panel for doing something trivial. :)

Comment: You have a [layout control](http://devexpress.com/products/vcl/exlayoutcontrol/Introduction.xml) in `DevExpress` suit.

Comment: In my opinion, using Layout Control for this would be even more overkill than using a Panel. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: @quad65, it was a comment not an answer. If I had DevExpress layout control at hand I would go for that solution because it implements alignment constraints the same way as modern Delphi does without adding extra panels as containers. but since I do not have it, I also use panels as containers and controlling the margins with `BorderWidth` (using D5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. That's why the feature was added in modern versions of Delphi. For Delphi 7 you have to use panels, `OnResize`, custom alignment etc.